# SQL add values of rows, if columns are switched

Tags: sql, postgresql

After a join of the same table, I have a result like this:

```
c1   c2  count
A    B   5
A    C   4
B    A   2
B    C   2
C    A   1
```

Now, the numbers should been added, if `c1` and `c2` are switched, like this:

```
c1   c2  count
A    B   7
A    C   5
B    C   2
```

How can this be done with a query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many databases support `least()` and `greatest()`.  If they are available, you can do:

```
select least(c1, c2) as c1, greatest(c1, c2) as c2, sum(count) as cnt
from (<your query here>) t
group by least(c1, c2), greatest(c1, c2);
```

In databases that don't support these functions, you can use `case`.

Note:  The semantics of `least()` and `greatest()` return `NULL` if either column is `NULL`, so you may need to be careful if either value could be `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `left join` to self join the table on inverse positions and returning those where `c1` is less than `c2`, or it had no matching row. Using `coalesce` to add `0` when the left joined `count` is `null`.

```
select 
    t.c1
  , t.c2
  , t.count + coalesce(s.count,0) as count
from t
  left join t as s
    on t.c1 = s.c2
   and t.c2 = s.c1
where t.c1 < t.c2 or s.c1 is null
```

rextester demo in sql server: http://rextester.com/VBQI62112

returns:

```
+----+----+-------+
| c1 | c2 | count |
+----+----+-------+
| A  | B  |     7 |
| A  | C  |     5 |
| B  | C  |     2 |
+----+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   t.c1
       , t.c2
       , t.cnt + CASE WHEN s.cnt IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE s.cnt END  as cnt
  FROM t
  LEFT JOIN 
       t as s
    ON t.c1 = s.c2
   AND t.c2 = s.c1
 WHERE t.c1 < t.c2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps join the output c1,c2 with the same c2,c1?

```
select t1.c1
      ,t1.c2
      ,sum(coalesce(t1.count,0), coalesce(t2.count,0))
from table t1
left join table t2
   on t1.c1 = t2.c2
   and t1.c2 = t2.c1
group by t1.c1, t1.c2
having t1.c1 < t1.c2
```